# In a paragraph how to make every first letter of the word into Capital letter using PHP

Tags: php, logic, capitalization

I am having a paragraph and i want to make every first letter of the word into a capital letter using PHP.

ex:

```
converting every first letter into capital letter.
```

should convert into

```
Converting Every First Letter Into Capital Letter.
```

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a function for that — [`ucwords()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php):

```
echo ucwords("converting every first letter into capital letter.");
```

Answer (score 5):

If this is strictly for presentation, you can also use CSS for this:

- capitalize: transforms the first character in each word to uppercase; all other characters remain unaffected — they’re not transformed to lowercase, but will appear as written in the document.

Example:

```
p {
    text-transform: capitalize
}
```

See

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-transform

Answer (score 1):

For converting every first letter capital use the below code

Ex)

```
<?php
$data = "converting every first letter into capital letter.";
echo ucwords($data);
?>
```

Output:
Converting Every First Letter Into Capital Letter.

For converting the first letter capital in a sentence use the below code
Ex)

```
<?php
$data = "converting every first letter into capital letter.";
echo ucfirst($data);
?>
```

Output:
Converting every first letter into capital letter.

For converting the first letter capital in all sentence use the below code.
Ex)

```
<?php
$string = "this is a first message. this is a second message. this is a third message! hope this helps.";

$string = strtolower($string);
echo preg_replace('/(^|[\.!?]"?\s+)([a-z])/e', '"$1" . ucfirst("$2")', $string); 
?>
```

Output:
This is a first message. This is a seconde message. This is a third message! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Nithin Raja, your example is great!
Below the code adjusted for >= PHP7
Thanks!

```
$string = "Olá, tudo bem? Esta é a minha segunda frase.\nAqui já estou na terceira. E agora encerrando o texto.";
$capitalize = preg_replace_callback('/(^|[\.!?]"?\s+)([a-z])/', function($parte){return $parte[1] . ucfirst($parte[2]);}, $string);
echo nl2br($capitalize);
```